# Searching for a term as both a single string and multi worded string

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm setting up my elastic instance in a schema-less manner (no up front mappings) and the application requires users be able to search against a field that contains a word that may or may not be tokenized into multiple strings. For example, the field may contain the word "ONETWO". The spec requires that a user should be able to search "ONETWO", "ONE", and "TWO" and retrieve that same document. There doesn't seem any easy way to accomplish this even with a custom tokenizer (and I don't think there SHOULD be an easy way to do this -- or any way at all). Just want to confirm my thoughts.

Comment: Have a look at [ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very easy to cater your requirement using the custom analyzer which uses the [n-gram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html), You can even pass it to a lowercase token filter, so that in your case even your text was `ONETWO` but if user searches for `one`, `One`, `ONE` he should get a result. Although for this you need to apply a different analyzer search time read more about it  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html.

Refer https://devticks.com/how-to-improve-your-full-text-search-in-elasticsearch-with-ngram-tokenizer-e346f29f8ddb for more information and let me know if you need any information.